# Selecting query sql with % as value character

Tags: php, mysql, sql, url

Hello i'm having a table in a database like this:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════╗
║              v3_url_alias                ║
╠════╦═══════════════╦═════════════════════╣
║ id ║    query      ║       keyword       ║
╠════╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ product_id=20 ║   540-65R38-K_028   ║
║  2 ║ product_id=21 ║ 18.00R33-EM_DT-150% ║
╚════╩═══════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

I'm using this table to make my urls friendly but as many know a % sign ain't a valid url character therefore making my browser getting a bad request.
I have a lot of entries in this table (1700 or so) and need a query to grab all the ones with % in the column keyword.

So I've tried doing that in MySQL and came up with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM v3_url_alias WHERE keyword LIKE '%%%';
```

This was returning all of my keywords as % is used as a wildcard.

My question how to retrieve every keyword containing a % character with SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an escape character!

**MySQL** has backslash (`\`) as default escape character:

```
SELECT * FROM v3_url_alias WHERE keyword LIKE '%\%%';
```

The **ANSI SQL** way is to use an `ESCAPE` clause to specify escape character, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM v3_url_alias WHERE keyword LIKE '%#%%' escape '#';
```

(This works with MySQL too, at least as long as `\` isn't specified.)

Comment: This did the job for me :)!

Comment: Just curious. why do you need `escape '\'` since `SELECT * FROM v3_url_alias WHERE keyword LIKE '%\%%';` works.

Comment: I don't know i've left that part out, i thought it was an addition to the description my bad for not noticing it's within the query so i'm wondering as well

Comment: @6339, it does?!? That must be some MySQL special. My answer is general ANSI SQL.

Comment: @Baklap4 does it works by using `SELECT * FROM v3_url_alias WHERE keyword LIKE '%\%%' escape '\';` ?. I mean with `escape '\'` keyword.

Comment: @jarlh Yes. But using `escape '\'` throughs an error!!

Answer (score 4):

Use square brackets.

```
SELECT * 
FROM v3_url_alias 
WHERE keyword LIKE '%[%]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using MySQL:

Use a backslash to escape character ( \ ).

```
SELECT * FROM v3_url_alias WHERE keyword LIKE '%\%%';
```